# Solaris 11.3.1 upgraded to 11.4.0 failing

Tags: solaris, upgrade, pkg

trying to upgrade from Solaris 11.3.1 to 11.4.0 and I keep running into a dependency problem that for the life of me I can't get past.

I'm guessing it needs a package that isn't available inside the release repo (11.4.0).  Maybe the package it needs to upgrade first is available in a 11.3 SRU?

I don't have a support contract so don't have access to the support repo (I'm a student and it's a lab box I am learning on).

Any ideas or suggestions?

**beadm list**

```
root@server:~# beadm list
BE         Flags Mountpoint Space  Policy Created          
--         ----- ---------- -----  ------ -------          
s11.2-12.6 -     -          26.01M static 2015-08-02 10:50 
s11.3.1    NR    -          26.41M static 2019-07-18 10:36
```

**pkg info**

```
root@server:~# pkg info entire
          Name: entire
       Summary: Incorporation to lock all system packages to the same build
   Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
                build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
                selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
                Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
      Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 0.5.11 (Oracle Solaris 11.3.1.5.3)
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.3.1.0.5.3
Packaging Date: August  1, 2018 01:01:46 AM 
          Size: 5.46 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.3:20180801T010146Z

root@server:~# pkg info -r entire
          Name: entire
       Summary: Incorporation to lock all system packages to the same build
   Description: This package constrains system package versions to the same
                build.  WARNING: Proper system update and correct package
                selection depend on the presence of this incorporation.
                Removing this package will result in an unsupported system.
      Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
         State: Not installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.0.0.1.15.0)
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 11.4.0.0.1.15.0
Packaging Date: August 17, 2018 12:42:03 AM 
          Size: 2.53 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/entire@11.4,5.11-11.4.0.0.1.15.0:20180817T004203Z
```

**pkg publisher**

```
root@server:~# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
```

**pkg update**

```
root@server:~# pkg update -nv --accept --be-name=s11.4.0 entire@11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0
Creating Plan (Solver setup): \
pkg update: No matching version of entire can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://solaris/entire@11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency consolidation/X/X-incorporation can be installed
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation can be installed
```

**pkg list**

```
root@server:~# pkg list -af entire
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
entire                                            11.4-11.4.0.0.1.15.0       ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.3     i--
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.2     ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.1     ---
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0     ---

root@server:~# pkg list -af consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation               11.4-11.4.0.0.1.14.0       ---
consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation               0.5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0    i--


root@server:~# pkg list -af consolidation/X/X-incorporation
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
consolidation/X/X-incorporation                   11.4-11.4.0.0.1.14.0       ---
consolidation/X/X-incorporation                   0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.2.1489  i--

root@server:~# pkg update -nv consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation 
No updates available for this image.
root@server:~# pkg update -nv consolidation/X/X-incorporation
No updates available for this image.
```

**pkg info**

```
root@server:~# pkg info consolidation/X/X-incorporation
          Name: consolidation/X/X-incorporation
       Summary: X consolidation incorporation
   Description: This incorporation constrains packages from the X Window System
                consolidation.
      Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 0.5.11
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.3.1.0.2.1489
Packaging Date: September 21, 2015 07:18:42 PM 
          Size: 5.53 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/consolidation/X/X-incorporation@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.1.0.2.1489:20150921T191842Z

root@server:~# pkg info consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation
          Name: consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation
       Summary: Image Packaging System consolidation incorporation
   Description: This incorporation constrains packages from the Image Packaging
                System consolidation.
      Category: System/Packaging
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 0.5.11
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.3.0.0.26.0
Packaging Date: July  5, 2015 08:34:35 PM 
          Size: 5.46 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation@0.5.11,5.11-0.175.3.0.0.26.0:20150705T203435


root@server:~# pkg info -r consolidation/X/X-incorporation                   
          Name: consolidation/X/X-incorporation
       Summary: userland consolidation incorporation (consolidation/X/X-incorporation)
   Description: This incorporation constrains packages from the userland
                consolidation
      Category: Meta Packages/Incorporations
         State: Not installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 11.4
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 11.4.0.0.1.14.0
Packaging Date: August 14, 2018 03:31:56 PM 
          Size: 2.52 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/consolidation/X/X-incorporation@11.4,5.11-11.4.0.0.1.14.0:20180814T153156Z


root@server:~# pkg info -r consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation
          Name: consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation
       Summary: Image Packaging System consolidation incorporation
   Description: This incorporation constrains packages from the Image Packaging
                System consolidation.
      Category: System/Packaging
         State: Not installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 11.4
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 11.4.0.0.1.14.0
Packaging Date: August 14, 2018 02:50:51 PM 
          Size: 2.52 kB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/consolidation/ips/ips-incorporation@11.4,5.11-11.4.0.0.1.14.0:20180814T145051Z
```

Comment: It's not supported, but https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468436/146 claims to have made it work via creative pkg editing.

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade you're attempting isn't possible, as discussed in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60977/gmpdi.html